# how can loop be used in following code so that if user enters any alphabet program again ask to enter a nuumber rahter than terminating a program?

Tags: java, loops, java.util.scanner

How can I apply a loop so that when a user enter any alphabet program it prompts the user to enter a number again rather than terminating a program?

```
public class prac{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your Cell Phone number : ");
        double phonenumber;

        phonenumber = in.nextDouble();                                
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you try to achieve this ? Maybe you should pick up a basic programming book, this is commonly described...

Answer (score 1):

Do it as follow

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[0-9]+$");
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
double phonenumber = 0;
String input;
Matcher matcher;
boolean stop=false;

while (!stop) {
     System.out.println("Enter your Cell Phone number : ");
     input = in.nextLine();  
     matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
     if (matcher.find()) {
           stop=true;
           phonenumber=Double.parseDouble(input);
     }          
}

System.out.println("User phone number is "+phonenumber);
```

**EDIT:**

```
^        match the beginning of the line
[0-9]    match a digit 
+        match 1 or more times
$        match the end of the line
```

Comment: But why the OP question choose `double` to store user's phone number? isn't `int` better?

Comment: I believe that there are phone numbers that extend past the `Integer` maximum value (2,147,483,647) aka 10 digits. In the USA, we use 10. I'm not so sure about the rest of the world , however he could have accounted for that... However, `double` is still the odd one out here.. he could have used a `long`, no? It has a max value of 9223372036854775807 which is for sure plenty of characters.

Comment: I never really used regex before, so I looked it up.  Does `"^[0-9]+$"` mean "beginning of line + one or more number that is between 0 and 9 (inclusive) + end of line"?  Just trying to understand.

Comment: @MChaker Thank you.  So matching the beginning and end of the line is just to make sure that nothing else is added besides numbers?

Comment: Yes, you got it @pepers